# Derive the density function of a non-central chi square with its moment-generating function.

Tags: probability, self-learning, density-function

I am looking to derive the non-central chi square density function. For this I have the moment generator function:
$$m.g.f= (1-2t)^{-n/2} \exp[\frac{\lambda t}{1-2t}]$$
and I know that the p.d.f of $X^2$ (where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$ is:
$$f_{X^2}(x) = \frac{e^{-(x+\mu^2)/2} \cosh (\mu \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}, \quad x \ge 0.$$

Wikipedia says that I can expand the cosh term using Taylor series to get this distribution function, but it is not clear to me how I should do it.

Comment: Do you want to go from the mgf to the pdf, or from the pdf to the mgf?

Comment: @J.G.   from the mgf to the pdf.